# Why should random numbers be drawn from a distribution?

Tags: random-generation

What does it mean to draw a number at random from a normal distribution? Why can't you just "draw" numbers at random? Why do you have to draw random numbers from a distribution?

Comment: I think you should thin about this question in reverse.  If you draw random numbers (say for example pulling numbers out of a hat) will it follow a distribution?  The answer is yes, although you may not know what the distribution is. So to answer your second questions yes you can just "draw" numbers at random.

Comment: @BabakP Your advice is good, but beware! Not all procedures for creating numbers arbitrarily will have probability distributions. Because this is a subtle concept, here's an explicit example couched in the language of discrete stochastic processes: draw values independently from a Bernoulli$(3/4)$ distribution at times $t\ge 1$ when the integer part of $\log_2(t)$ is even and otherwise draw the values from a Bernoulli$(1/4)$ distribution. What could "the" distribution of this process possibly be? In light of this, one has to question whether your answer to Q2 even makes sense.

Comment: @whuber, very true.  I suppose I was thinking more simplistically for this answer but you bring up a very good point.

Comment: @whuber Wouldn't your example be a mixture distribution?

Comment: @Peter Interesting thought; but no: make a plot of the expected mean as a function of $t$ to see what's going on.  (Use a logarithmic scale for $t$.)  There are deep conceptual issues involved here: randomness is not arbitrariness, nor is all randomness describable with a (fixed) probability distribution.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "draw numbers at random?", *without* implying an underlying distribution? I must admit to being skeptical that this could even be a coherent notion.

Comment: When I say random number, I mean drawing a random number without knowing the distribution. For example, if you were to close your eyes and just pick random numbers from your head, you are not drawing numbers from a particular distribution. The distribution can be fitted after the random numbers are chosen but I still don't see why one needs to know the distribution before drawing random numbers. Why is randomness contingent on an a priori distribution?

Comment: Phil, finding numbers in your head is demonstrably *not* random. Randomness implies certain properties that subjective generation of numbers does not have.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to produce a "sample" that is representative of the type of distribution that you wish to compare with your real data and its expected distribution as well, for example, uniform, normal, exponential, and a whole host of others.

Comment: And there isn't an alternative. You cannot sample without some distribution by default. Most imperative computer languages have a standard library function that produces random numbers in a uniform distribution between 0 and 1.